# Stop function while running in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous

### Introduction

I am building a sorting algorithms visualizer for studying purposes, and i have a `sortArray()` function that takes care of animating the array being sorted. As you can see in the code.

and it works fine, but the problem is that i wanted to give the array takes some time to get sorted, and i wanted a way to stop this function while running.

### What I've Tried So Far

After i realised that i had this problem, i thought that a "Stop" button would be a good way to solve my problem i added a new state called "Abort", and the original idea was that while the `sortArray()` function is running, the function would check everytime if the abort state is set to true, and if it is, the function would stop. and of course, it didn't work.

after that my previous attempt had failed, i deleted the "abort" state from the code and transformed it into a normal variable, thinking that the problem maybe was related to the `setState` function being async, and it didn't work either.

after that i did some research, but i didn't found anything useful.

### The Code:

```
resetArray(){
        const arrayToSort = [];
        const prevChanged = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.numberOfItems; i++) {
            arrayToSort.push(this.RandomIntBetweenRange(5, 1000));
        }
        this.setState({ arrayToSort, prevChanged, abort: false });
    }

generateNewArray(){
    this.setState({abort: true},{
        this.resetArray();
    });
}

async SortArray(algo){
    let sortedArrayAnim = algo(this.state.arrayToSort);
    let arrayToSort = this.state.arrayToSort;
    let prevChanged = this.state.prevChanged;

    for (let index = 0; index < sortedArrayAnim.length; index++) {
        const [i,j] = sortedArrayAnim[index];

        if(this.state.abort){
            console.log(abort);
            return null;
        }
            let temp = arrayToSort[i];
            arrayToSort[i] = arrayToSort[j];
            arrayToSort[j] = temp;

            prevChanged.push(i,j);

            if(index == sortedArrayAnim.length - 1){
                prevChanged.push(arrayToSort.length + 1, arrayToSort.length + 1);
                this.setState({prevChanged});
            }

            this.setState({ arrayToSort,prevChanged });
            await sleep(10);
    }
}

render() {
    const {arrayToSort} = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="main-div">
            {arrayToSort.map((value, idx) => (
                <div className="array-item" key={idx} style={{height: value, width: 800 / this.state.numberOfItems, backgroundColor: this.getColor(idx)}}>

                </div>
            ))}

            <button onClick={() => this.generateNewArray()}>Generate new array</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.SortArray(BubbleSort)}>Bubble Sort</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.SortArray(InsertionSort)}>Insertion Sort</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.SortArray(QuickSort)}>Quick Sort</button>
            <input type="number" min="5" max="1500" onChange={(event) => this.handleOnChange(event)} defaultValue={this.state.numberOfItems}/>
        </ div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something involving a Web-worker?

Structure the class something like this

```
class LongOperation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      running: false,
      results: null,
      worker: null,
    }
  }

  startLongOp(){
     const worker = new Worker('yourIsolatedOp.js')
     //...setup
     this.setState({
       running: true,
       worker: worker,
     })
  }

  cancel() {
    if(running) { 
      this.state.worker.terminate() 
    }
    this.setState({
      running: false, 
      worker: null,
    })
  }

  render() {
   //Do your rendering
   <button onClick={e => this.startLongOp()}>Start</button>
   <button onClick={e => this.cancel()}>Cancel</button>
  }
}

//while loop:
while(this.state.running) {
  //do stuff
}
```

You could also probable do it with a while loop, but it would be on the UI thread. I have not tried this, it is just a sketch from the top of my head. Now designing a concurrent sort is going to be the bigger challenge... Workers are going to be the easiest if you can isolate it.

*note: I didn't go into details on how to deal with the web-worker passing data etc.. but you can easily find it. I see no reason you can't update the state from these messages.